# What kind of spider is this? Brown with white spots

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image: brown spider with white spots]

It was found in Houston, Texas, but I've never seen one before. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Why did you have to kill it by burning it? Couldn't you just step on it? Or, even better, just leave it alone?

Comment: 1) Your pictures are really small. Don't you have better ones? 2) You displayed twice the same picture. Why? 3) The fact that you were scared of this little creature and decided to offer it one of the worst possible death is up to your own standards in ethics but it is certainly not a necessary information to ID this species.

Comment: The fact that you killed it is irrelevant and apparently unsettling to some people. Stop putting it back in your question.

Answer (score 7):

[Sub-adult tropical orb weaver spider](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/misc/spiders/tropical_orb_weaver.htm).  "*Its range is largely circum-Caribbean, occurring in Florida, Louisiana, and Texas along the Gulf Coast of the United States.*"

[image]

Harmless to humans and considered beneficial.

> Bites of this species are not known to cause serious effects to humans. ... The web probably catches many moths and other night flying insects; these spiders may be particularly beneficial along woodland borders of field agroecosystems and within orchards.